# RabbitMQ Cluster Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, rabbitmq

We have a chatting application. It's a 3 cluster set-up with below config on production:

EC2 - t3.medium
Volume - gp2, 8gb storage, 100 iops and 150 throughput

Can someone suggest the recommended configuration for production environment?

Answer (score 2):

Please read this blog post about "production checklist":
https://www.rabbitmq.com/production-checklist.html

Also, I suggest the rabbtimq prometheus/grafana configuration see https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html and https://youtu.be/NWISW6AwpOE